# how to fill the dropdownlist in grip grouping control using syncfusion in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, syncfusion

I am having a **grid grouping control** in `syncfusion` `asp.net` with first column cell type as combobox.here I need to fill the dropdownlist in pageload.I wrote the below code:

```
Sqlcommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select item_Id, item_Name from productsnrwmtrls where item_Ctgry in('R','B')", con);
         sqldataadapter   da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
           Datatable dtLocl = new DataTable();
            da.Fill(dtLocl);

        DropDownList ddlrwmtrl1 = (DropDownList)GridGroupingControl1.FindControl("ddlrwmtrl");

        ddlrwmtrl1.DataTextField = "item_Name";
        ddlrwmtrl1.DataValueField = "item_Id";
        ddlrwmtrl1.DataSource = dtLocl;
        ddlrwmtrl1.DataBind();
```

But at this line `ddlrwmtrl1.DataTextField = "item_Name";` it is showing error : **Object Reference is not set to an instance of an object**.

Comment: Does ddlrwmtrl1  != null ?

Comment: No it is showing null in ddlrwmtrl1  DropDownList ddlrwmtrl1 = (DropDownList)GridGroupingControl1.FindControl("ddlrwmtrl"); at this line when I checked with debugger

Comment: So if ddlrwmtrl1  it is logical the error you get. Try to initialize the ctl with other way :)

Comment: DropDownList ddlrwmtrl = ggcPname.FormEditCell.FindControl("ddlrwmtrl") as DropDownList; I tried with this line also but still it showing the same error

Comment: protected void GridGroupingControl1_RowDataBound(object sender, RowDataBoundEventArgs e)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < e.Row.Cells.Count; i++)
        {
         if (((Syncfusion.Web.UI.WebControls.Grid.Grouping.GridCell)(e.Row.Cells[i])).ColumnDescriptor != null)
            {
             if (((Syncfusion.Web.UI.WebControls.Grid.Grouping.GridCell)(e.Row.Cells[i])).ColumnDescriptor.Name == "item_Name")
                {
                  DropDownList ddlpname = (DropDownList)e.Row.Cells[i].FindControl("ddlrwmtrl");
 }
}
}I tried like this also but ddlpname is showing null.Where I am wrong

Answer (score 1):

You can fill the dropdownlist in Syncfusion GridGroupingControl by using Rowdatabound. 
Add the dropdown as an Item Template in ASPX file:

```
[**aspx**]

    <syncfusion:GridColumnDescriptor MappingName="City" HeaderText="City">
          <ItemTemplate>
               <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlCity" runat="server"></asp:DropDownList>
          </ItemTemplate>
    </syncfusion:GridColumnDescriptor>
```

RowDataBound Event

```
**[cs]**


  protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
            GetData();
        this.GridGroupingControl1.RowDataBound += GridGroupingControl1_RowDataBound;
    }

    protected void GridGroupingControl1_RowDataBound(object sender,RowDataBoundEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Element.Kind == DisplayElementKind.Record)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < e.Row.Cells.Count; i++)
            {
                if (((GridCell)e.Row.Cells[i]).ColumnDescriptor.Name == "City")
                {
                    myConnection = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString);
                    myConnection.Open();
                    DropDownList ddl = (DropDownList)e.Row.Cells[i].FindControl("ddlCity");
                    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT Distinct City FROM Employees", 
                                             myConnection);
                    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
                    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                    da.Fill(ds);
                    myConnection.Close();
                    ddl.DataSource = ds;
                    ddl.DataTextField = "City";
                    ddl.DataValueField = "City";
                    ddl.DataBind();
                    ddl.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("--Select--", "0"));
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

You will get the grid with dropdown like below

[image]